# Magento product price before catalogue price rules are applied

Tags: magento, product

I'd like to be able to show the price of a product in my Magento store before the catalogue price rules are applied to it. Ideally I'd just like the number typed in the "price" box in the backend with no tax, no rules, no modification of any type.

`$_product->getFinalPrice()` is great for showing the final price after all these rules, and is normally just what I need. Is there something that shows the "non-final" price?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's a standard product object, you can just use `$_product->getPrice()` which should retrieve the value entered in the price field on the backend for that product.

Comment: remember that you'll also have to set the locale and currency before rendering the price